# makefile: no executable created

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, g++

I have used openGL with glut before and SDL2 on its own before. Now I try to make an optimized project with Glew, SDL2 and OpenGL. I want it to be able to run on Linux(I mainly use Debian),OSX and Windows. So I tried to write my own makefile. This code should only create a window for me.
Im developing on osx.

I have only my main.cpp, Display.cpp and Display.h

This is what i tried:

```
#my compiler
CC=g++

#my program name
PRGNAME=booom

#library search directory
LIBDIR=-L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib

#library names
#uses libSDL.a, libGLEW.a
LIBNAME=-lSDL -lGLEW

#includes for libraries
INCLUDES=-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include

#my compiler options
CFLAGS=-c -Wall


all: main.o Display.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) -o $(PRGNAME) main.o Display.o

#main.cpp is the dependency of main.o
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) main.cpp

Display.o: Display.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) Display.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o booom
```

I get a main.o and a Display.o file, but i don't get an executable.

When I do "make clean && make" this is my output:

```
macbook-mehrschwein:Booom Mehrschwein$ make clean && make
rm -rf *o booom
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL -lGLEW main.cpp
clang: warning: -lSDL: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lGLEW: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/lib'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL -lGLEW Display.cpp
clang: warning: -lSDL: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lGLEW: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/lib'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL -lGLEW -o booom main.o Display.o
clang: warning: -lSDL: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lGLEW: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: main.o: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: Display.o: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wall'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I /usr/include'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I /usr/local/include'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/lib'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib'
macbook-mehrschwein:Booom Mehrschwein$
```

Comment: When linking, put the libraries *after* the object files. And don't use linker-flags (like libraries etc.) when compiling the source files to object files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `-c` flag that you use in all stages.
It means to compile an object file but not to link.
Remove it for your `all` target. Like:

```
all: main.o Display.o
$(CC) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) -o $(PRGNAME) main.o Display.o
```

This fixed the problem with linking.
Now ensure that you have libSDL in the folders you specify.

Answer (score 0):

new version with:

```
all: main.o Display.o
    $(CC) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) -o $(PRGNAME) main.o Display.o

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) main.cpp 

Display.o: Display.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) Display.cpp
```

no warnings for Display.o and main.o anymore.

the error that i get now:

```
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include main.cpp 
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include Display.cpp 
g++ -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o booom main.o Display.o -lSDL -lGLEW
ld: library not found for -lSDL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

EDIT: The name is libSDL2.a, not libSDL.a

but now it tells me that he can't find libGlew.a

libGLEW.a is in /usr/lib

libSDL2.a is in /usr/local/lib

do they both need to be in the same directory?

EDIT2:

## Update

I changed a few things, i now build GLEW into "/usr/local", so everything is in the same dir.

my makefile:

```
#my compiler
CC=g++

#my program name
PRGNAME=booom

#library search directory
LIBDIR=-L/usr/local/lib

#library names
#uses libSDL2.a, libGLEW.a
LIBNAME=-lSDL2 -lGLEW 

#includes for libraries
INCLUDES=-I/usr/local/include

#my compiler options
CFLAGS=-c -Wall


all: main.o Display.o
    $(CC) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBNAME) -o $(PRGNAME) main.o Display.o

#main.cpp is the dependency of main.o
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) main.cpp

Display.o: Display.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) Display.cpp 

clean:
    rm -rf *o booom
```

my error now:

```
rm -rf *o booom
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/local/include main.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -I/usr/local/include Display.cpp 
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lGLEW  -o booom main.o Display.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      Display::Clear(float, float, float, float) in Display.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      Display::Clear(float, float, float, float) in Display.o
  "_glCullFace", referenced from:
      Display::Display(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Display.o
  "_glEnable", referenced from:
      Display::Display(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Display.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

seams like i got a 32-bit version, while i need a 64-bit version, but i have build that on my own, and don't really know what i have done wrong. normally you also have do do something like ./config before building. but there is no config for GLEW. the only solution that i found on google involves macports, but i would love to do it without macports

Comment: As I wrote, are you sure that you have `libSDL` installed and it can be found in your library paths?

Comment: yes, libSDL2 is in /usr/local/lib. thats the default path, where it should be, defined by the sdl2 makefile for osx. does it need to be in /usr/lib? i though  i could just do "-L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib" to use both

Comment: Then should it be `-lSDL2` instead of `-lSDL`?

Comment: So now you have `ld: library not found for -lSDL2` message?

Comment: i have this after changing -lSDL to -lSDL2: "library not found for -lGLEW"       seams like he can find -lSDL2 now

Comment: This means that you don't have libGLEW. But that's another issue. Have you installed it or built?

Comment: look at my edit above. now i have glew and sdl2 where it needs to be. its just not working correctly yet